# HTML editor for iOS

Tags: html, ios, html-editor

Can someone suggest any native iOS component for editing HTML?

I couldn't find any googling.

Comment: what do you mean? Sorry, I didn't really understand the question

Comment: In my iOS app i need to edit HTML. It is usually just formatted text. I wonder if there is an editor (open source or paid component) which allows not to deal with HTML tags but to do formatting simple.

Comment: Are you looking for syntax highlighting?

Comment: I am looking for text formatting.

Comment: Looking for the same thing a UIControl that allows basic html text strong tags links etc

Comment: We had to create our own HTML/JS editor. And it sucks. Not as good as native UIKit control.

Answer (score 3):

[Textastic](http://www.textasticapp.com/) maybe? You'd better search iTunes for related applications and choose yourself.

Comment: In my iOS app i need to edit HTML. It is usually just formatted text. I wonder if there is an editor (open source or paid component) which allows not to deal with HTML tags but to do formatting simple.

Answer (score 0):

You might look at TinyMCE or CKEditor.  Both are Javascript editors for creating HTML.

Comment: I have been thinking about it but how to load it in UIWebView? It is not just one HTML file.

Answer (score 0):

Solution here is to create custom JS HTML editor adopted to the touch screen.

Comment: Did you publish the customed JS HTML editor on GitHub or some other website?

Comment: We did not publish it. Actually we don't like how HTML component works in iOS. Not as responsive and flashy as native controls.

Answer (score 0):

I found this tool, its a full featured Html editor like frontpage. https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/a-real-html-editor/id732000017?mt=8