# HTML editor view for iOS

Tags: html, ios

The question is quite similar to [HTML editor for iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10105931/html-editor-for-ios), but i couldn't find an answer. The thing I need is an HTML editor window in the application, where I can create a formatted web document. Not a complicated one, just formatted text in HTML style. As a result I need to get the text with tags from window form. Is there any framework or something which allows something like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[TinyMCE](http://www.tinymce.com/tryit/full.php) and [wysihtml5](http://xing.github.com/wysihtml5/) work on iOS, and [DTCoreText](https://github.com/Cocoanetics/DTCoreText) also supports basic wysiwyg HTML.